# Mysql Cache storing and auto reset on event of database table insert/update

Tags: mysql, caching

is it possible? to cache mysql output and use it. and the cache will auto reset as soon as database table got changes?

Detailed explanation:

select col2,col2,col3 from table1;

this output will be stored somewhere .... so when i want to use it, it don't have to connect mysql.

later when any insert update action happen to table1 . the cache will auto loads ( new data ).

Reason why i need this, 
- there is 1000s of single process running from some background script.
- and each process is requires some data from table1. and has to make connections.
- so if some how i could access this from cache then i do not have to connect database server everytime. and process can be smoother and faster.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL [already has a query cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html) ... have you looked into that?

Comment: Yes, already. but for that only requires mysql connection.

Comment: Are you using a programming language here?

Comment: i am connection mysql using shell script.  master.sh file will trigger all process.php ( X 1000s )  Files